# ASP.NET Asynchronous request callback

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

If I call a WebService Async using ASP.NET will the callback code still run even if the user is no longer physically on the page, or when the user leaves the page will the process terminate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the user close the connection with the server, and your processing takes too much time, you get a throw of "connection close" and your process will terminate.

If you do not like that and you wish to keep the processing make a new thread that is not depend from the connection with the user, and synchronize it with the user return. If the user close the connection then the thread will finish normally, just you not show the results.